# bridge library between QML and ReactJs

Tags: c++, reactjs, react-native, qml, bridge

Is there possible use reactjs in qml project in Qt?
I want to use some react component in my qml or on the other hand is it possible use QML in react native ?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing 2 different technologies. QML output is a widget drawn using OpenGL, React output is HTML/Javascript used mostly in  a web browser. how do you plan to combine it, and most importantly for what? of course you can use a WebAssembly backand and draw QML in a WebBrowser but again, for what? The same things  you can do in pure React or in pure QML

Answer (score 0):

I developed a library for that purpose. It's been using in production at one of my client company.

See the source code here: https://github.com/longseespace/react-qml